# Problems with setting boolean to true with http Put

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I've been working some time on this project. Maybe today too much, because i got a (properly simple) problem with my PUT method.

I've got a HTML table with some informations which include a boolean.

```
<tr ng-if="A.donepost == false"  ng-repeat="A in author | filter: todofilter | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
                    <td>{{A.id}}</td>
                    <td ng-model="todoregistered">{{A.registered | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td ng-model="todoauthor">{{A.author}}</td>
                    <td ng-model="tododescription">{{A.description}}</td>
                    <td ng-model="tododeveloper">{{A.developer}}</td>
                    <td ng-model="todoinprogress">{{A.inprogress}}</td>
                    <!--<td>{{A.donepost}}</td>-->
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="editTodo(A.id)" >edit </a> |
                        <a href="#" ng-click="deleteTodo(A.id)">delete</a> |
                        <a href="#" ng-click="DoneTodo(A.id)">done</a> |
                        <a ng-if="A.inprogress == false" href="#" ng-click="StartTodo(A.id)">Start</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

This boolean should be changed to true when the "Start" button is pressed.

My http method looks like this.

```
        $scope.StartTodo = function (id) {

             $scope.codingtodo = {

                  registered: $scope.todoregistered,
                  author: $scope.todoauthor,
                  description: $scope.tododescription,
                  developer: $scope.tododeveloper,
                  donepost: false,

                  $scope.author[id].inprogress: true
             };
             console.log(id)
             console.log($scope.codingtodo)
             $http({
                   method: 'PUT',
                   url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/resources/posts/' + id,

                   data: $scope.codingtodo, // Ive tried two things here
                   data: $scope.inprogress == true, // Ive tried two things here

                   console.log(data)
                   dataType: 'json'
             }).success(function (data) {
                   $scope.todo.push(data);
                   console.log('Successfully started!');
                   $scope.error = null;
             }).error(function (data, status) {
                   if (status == 401) {
                        $scope.error = "You are not authenticated to update these data";
                        return;
                   }
                        $scope.error = data;
             });
        };
```

my suspect is that the ng-model in  is stupid. but as i said, i've worked too many hours on this in a row, so im kindda brainlagging atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the HTML to get the whole Todo, instead of its ID. 
Then it worked.

```
<a ng-if="todo.inprogress == false" href="#" ng-click="StartTodo(todo)">Start</a>
```

And then i changed the JS. Now it twerks. Nice.

```
$scope.PauseTodo = function (todo) {
                     todo.inprogress = false;
                     $http({
                           method: 'PUT',
                           url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/resources/posts/' + todo.id,
                           data: todo,
                           dataType: 'json'
                     }).success(function (data) {
                           $scope.todo.push(data);
                           console.log('Successfully started!');
                           $scope.error = null;
                     }).error(function (data, status) {
                           if (status == 401) {
                                $scope.error = "You are not authenticated to update these data";
                                return;
                           }
                                $scope.error = data;
                     });
                };
```